# Datediff Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @Date nvarchar(200)
set @Date=GetDate()
execute @Date
SELECT LName,DATEDIFF(yy,DOB,@Date) AS DiffDate
from Employees
```

the code actually works and shows the current age of the employes, but in messages it says "Could not find stored procedure 'Feb  9 2015  6:06PM'"
Is there something i should do?

Comment: remove the line execute @Date, EXECUTE is designed to execute procedures

Comment: Easy enough, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are doing `execute @Date` ? that is why you are getting the error. `EXECUTE` is use for executing a procedure.

Just remove that, and the error will go away.

See: [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Since your `@Date` holds `Feb 9 2015 6:06PM` and `execute @Date` tries to find a proc with this name and hence the error.